# OpenGl ES 2.0 invalid_Value

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to use different colors on each vertecies, but when 
I run program it doesn't draw anything.The GLES20.getError(); function returns an INVALID_VALUE error, But i have no idea where it could be. Could anyone help me where the error is,Please?

```
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.util.Log;


import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.sql.SQLOutput;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class glDraw {
    private float[] vertecies={
            0.0f,2.0f,0.0f,
            1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
           -1.0f,0.0f,0.0f
    };
    private float[] colors={
            1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.5f,
            0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.5f,
            0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.5f
    };
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;
    private final String vertexShaderCode=
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;"+
            "attribute vec4 vPosition;"+
            "attribute vec4 a_Color"+
            "varying vec4 v_Color"+
            "void main(){"+
            "   v_Color=a_Color;"+
            "   gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;"+
            "   gl_PointSize=10.0;"+
            "}";
    private final String fragmentShaderCode=
            "precision mediump float;"+
            "varying vec4 v_Color;"+
            "void main(){"+
            "   gl_FragColor=v_Color;"+
            "}";
    private int ShaderProgram;
    public static int glLoadShader(int Type,String shaderCode){
        int shader=GLES20.glCreateShader(Type);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        return shader;
    }
    private int matrixHandle;
    public glDraw(){
        ByteBuffer vbb= ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertecies.length*4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer=vbb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertecies);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        ByteBuffer cbb= ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        colorBuffer=cbb.asFloatBuffer();
        colorBuffer.put(colors);
        colorBuffer.position(0);

        int vertexShader=glLoadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader=glLoadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,fragmentShaderCode);
        ShaderProgram=GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        GLES20.glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, vertexShader);
        GLES20.glAttachShader(ShaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(ShaderProgram);
    }
    public void drawTriangle(float[] mvpMatrix,float[] color){
        GLES20.glUseProgram(ShaderProgram);
        int PositionAttrib = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(ShaderProgram, "vPosition");
        int ColorAttrib = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(ShaderProgram,"a_Color");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(PositionAttrib);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(ColorAttrib);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(PositionAttrib, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexBuffer);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(ColorAttrib, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, colorBuffer);
        matrixHandle= GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(ShaderProgram,"uMVPMatrix");
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(matrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        Integer a=GLES20.glGetError();
        Log.e("szar",a.toString());
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertecies.length / 3);
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(PositionAttrib);
    }
}
```

And tihs is my Renderer class:

```
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

/**
 * Created by Lacko on 2015.07.29..
 */
public class GLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0f,0,0,0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float ratio=(float) width/(float)height;
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 0.1f, 500);
    }
    public int x=0;
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1.78f, 0, 0, 1, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glDraw draw =new glDraw();
        Matrix.translateM(mMVPMatrix,0,0,0,-3);
        draw.drawTriangle(mMVPMatrix,new float[]{ 1,0,0,1f});
        Matrix.rotateM(mMVPMatrix,0,x,0,1,0);
        Matrix.translateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -1);
        draw.drawTriangle(mMVPMatrix,new float[]{1,1,0,0.5f});
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you have a viewport() by the way?

Comment: You should check the success of your shader compilations. The vertex shader is missing a couple of semicolons.

Comment: I checked it, I put the missing semicolons n it, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about JAVA OpenGL but I want you to check two things.

1. If you need to create FBO and bind it as a render target.
2. If you forgot putting a viewport().

**UPDATE**

1 is not necessary for general systems.

2 is not necessary if you don't need to change the size of rendering view, but I recommend to call this anyway.

- According to the what @Reto Koreadi mentioned, you missed semicolons in vertex shader.

Comment: The default viewport size is the initial size of the rendering window/view. So that should be fine if the view is not resized. Also, if you render directly to the display, you don't need any FBOs.

Comment: @Reto Koreadi: I was wondering if at least one FBO is necessary there like IOS. So we don't have to call viewport() in any mobile OS if we don't need to change the full sized view? Good information.

Comment: It's always a good idea to call `glViewport()`, just to be sure that it has the right value. It typically belongs in some kind of method that is invoked when the window/view is resized. But even if the OP missed it, I don't think it would keep them from getting any output. In Android, you normally render to the default framebuffer when rendering to the display. I've only seen it on iOS that there's always an FBO.

Comment: @Reto Koreadi: You got me. I just checked the official opengl document and run mine, it works well. Thanks !